# MySQL Master-Slave replication foreign key constraint error

Tags: replication, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

This is the cluster setup:

```
------       ------
| m1 |  ---  | m2 |
------       ------
  ||           ||
------       ------
| s1 |       | s2 |
------       ------
```

`m1` and `m2` run `mariadb-server-10.1` version `10.1.18+maria-1~jessie`.

`m1` and `s2` run `mariadb-server-10.1` version `10.1.18+maria-1~wheezy`.

Nodes `m1` and `m2` are in a Galera Cluster, and replication between these nodes works fine. There is also an arbitrator node running on a separate server.

`s1` is a slave node to `m1`, and `s2` is a slave node to `m2`. The replication to slave nodes is using classic MySQL replication.

Now, the issue here is that the slave nodes needed to be started from fresh state. This was the process to start the replication:

1. `service mysql stop` on slave node.
2. Empty `/var/lib/mysql` on slave node.
3. Run `innobackupex -u user -p password` on master node.
4. Run `innobackupex -u user -p password --apply-log /path/to/backup` on the master node.
5. Copy database backup files to slave server.
6. Run `innobackupex --copy-back /path/to/backup` on slave server.
7. Run `chown -r mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/*` on slave server to fix permissions.
8. `service mysql start` on slave server.

After this, I started `mysql -u root -p password`, and issued this command:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='m1', MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='password', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mariadb-bin.NNNNNN', MASTER_LOG_POS=nnn;
START SLAVE;
```

Values for `NNNNNN` and `nnn` were retrieved from `xtrabackup_binlog_info` file from the backup files.

Now, this process worked perfectly between `m1` and `s1`. However, with `m2` and `s2`, it generates an error message (I split the error message to multiple lines for better readability):

```
Could not execute Write_rows_v1 event on table db.table;
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`db`.`table`, CONSTRAINT `FK3EBA76781F6AACF1` FOREIGN KEY (`job`)
REFERENCES `table2` (`id`)), Error_code: 1452; handler error
HA_ERR_NO_REFERENCED_ROW; the event's master log mariadb-bin.000710, end_log_pos 1523526
```

I have tried to repeat the process again a couple of times without any success.

I have also issued `RESET MASTER` on `m2` to reset the replication log file in case it had some corruption.

I am running out of ideas what is happening here and how I can restart replication correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: use  set global foreign_key_checks=0; and then try restoring and after restoration revert it to set global foreign_key_checks=1;

Comment: This was tried too, and still the same error message appears.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have used a multi-master configuration for m1 and m2 and a master-slave config for m1-s1 and m2-s2. Currently, the multi-master configuration does not support write actions on the tables with foreign keys. Thus, when there is a write action on either m1 or m2, the error occurs.

**test to debug:** set up a master-slave config for m1-s1 and m2-s2 without connecting m1 and m2. If both of them work as expected, then you can confirm that the foreign keys issue is due to the multi-master m1-m2 config.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I cannot test it right now since I am no longer involved with this stuff. The explanation sounds solid though.